# How to send one bash command to multiple byobu windows?

Tags: bash, byobu

I have a prompt. I want to send a `clear` or `ls` to all my byobu windows (opened with F2), by typing it only once.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was such a phenomenal question, and something that I've been wanting to do for so long, that I just put a couple of scripts together, added to Byobu-5.73, and released the new feature :-)

As of that version of Byobu, you can now use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> to enter a command and send to all panes (splits), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> to enter a command and send to all windows.

You can watch a demo here: http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2014/09/apply-updates-to-multiple-systems.html

This feature is available in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (trusty), or you can always install the latest version from ppa:byobu/ppa or build/install from source.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: This is awesome! Just used it to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` on a bunch of PCs in my LAN, and saving a nice amount of time!